# Should font in figure match caption font or document font?

Tags: fonts, captions, fontsize

I am aware that the writing in a figure (for example text on axis, in block diagrams etc) should match the same font and font size as the rest of the document for consistency. However, IEEEtran.cls provided by IEEE sets the font size of a figure caption to be smaller than 'normal' text (8pt for captions and 10pt for 'normal' text). So which size should the font of the axis be in this case, 8pt or 10pt?

Personally speaking, I would say it is more important for the text in a figure to be consistent with the caption of the figure, rather than the rest of the document, since the figure and its caption are more tightly linked to each other than to the rest of the document.

I've searched around for guidelines for a while now, but the best I could find were examples of papers irrelated to the question but which did include a figure or table. Most have the axis labels the same size as the caption (smaller than body), but still a non negligible amount of published papers have axis labels larger than its caption (same as body).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Good question! However, I feel this may be off-topic (w.r.t. TeX/LaTeX). The style of the annotation text in figures is determined by the publishing houses. Good journals may hire good designers to design and specify every detail in their publications. Good programmers may implement all such details, or only partially. But, in general, authors will have little to no control on how the text appears, except in their manuscript. You may have a good reason for figure annotation text and figure caption text to be the same, but the publishing houses may disagree. I'd say ultimately it's about taste.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I agree it has little to nothing to do TeX, so should I will revoke my question? This actually is for an undergrad project I'm writing, so it is nice to know it is essentially up to taste.